# Apex Row-Level Security is not applied to OwnerId field

Tags: apex, security, sharing

It seems that the Apex row-level security enforcement by `with sharing` keyword is not applied to the field `OwnerId`, when it is directly passed to update statement.

```
public with sharing class MyRecordUpdate {
  // ...
  public void changeOwnerToMe(Id recordId) {
    MyRecord__c rec = new MyRecord__c(Id=recordId, OwnerId=UserInfo.getUserId());
    update rec;
  }
}
```

In the above code, supposing that the `MyRecord__c` object is private in Organization-Wide sharing defaults, and each records are shared by manually. Its Object-level security = CRUD enabled, and Field-level security = Not set.

If the record specified by `recordId` is owned by other user and granted read-only access to the current user, the modification of `OwnerId` should raise an insufficient privilege error (it actually behaves that from standard UI or REST API). But when executing `MyRecordUpdate#changeOwnerId()` in the context of user with standard profile (not admin user), it silently succeeds the owner modification.

This only happens when the update statement argument record is created by `new`, not applied when queried from SOQL. Also it will not happen to other fields, like `Name`.

```
public with sharing class MyRecordUpdate {
  // ...

  // supposing that context user is granted read-only access to `recordId` record

  public void changeOwnerToMeUsingQuery(Id recordId) {
    MyRecord__c rec = [SELECT Id FROM MyRecord__c WHERE Id = :recordId];
    rec.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    update rec; // throws INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY error
  }

  public void updateName(Id recordId, String name) {
    MyRecord__c rec = new MyRecord__c(Id=recordId, Name=name);
    update rec; // throws INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY error
  }
}
```

Is there anyone who encountered to this situation? I've tested the above in my scratch org.

EDIT: Added the code to demonstrate this issue.
https://github.com/stomita/apex-rls-ownerid-issue

Comment: I tried this scenario in a developer org. Both `changeOwnerToMe` & `changeOwnerToMeUsingQuery` methods were able to update the OwnerId field (code run under Standard User context, following the instructions you have mentioned). But I did get insufficient access exceptions for the Name and Text01__c fields, which was expected. While the OwnerId update can be restricted with some additional apex code, its weird that the field is getting updated by an user having read only access to the record.

Comment: Also, I noted the following: `The following field types don’t return a FieldPermissions record because they are assumed to always be readable and writable.

    OwnerId` in the SOAP API developer guide [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_fieldpermissions.htm]. While its not directly related to the problem here, it sounds like OwnerId field is handled quite differently by Salesforce when compared to the other field.

Comment: In a new scratch org I found `changeOwnerToMeUsingQuery` doesn't throw insufficient privilege error (unexpected), but the other environment it throws (expected). I cannot figure the difference of them.

Comment: Sounds like a Salesforce bug to me. I'll try and run few more scenarios on this.